# Printing an array of pointers using double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Following other inquiries I found on this site, I'm trying to print an array of pointers to characters (strings), by using a **double pointer as follows:

```
char *input=malloc(128), *color[7]={0}, **colors=malloc(8); 

fgets(input, 128, stdin);
sscanf(input, "%s%s%s%s%s%s", &color[0], &color[1], &color[2], &color[3], &color[4], &color[5]);
color[6]=NULL;  
colors=color;

while(*colors)
printf("%s ", colors++);
```

The output I receive from the above seems to be choking every input string down to 4 bytes and then overflowing if it is more than four, because if I type: "black red gold white green blue", for instance, I receive: "blacred red goldwhitgreeblue goldwhitgreeblue whitgreeblue greeblue blue." Very frustrating.

I tried dereferencing colors++, like I saw in other examples, but this causes the program to crash. Ultimately, the printf is just for debugging. This is part of a char ** (void) function I'm trying to create to assign what it is I'm trying to print to a local variable of type char **. How can I fix this?

Comment: `malloc()` is not magic...

Comment: Okay, cool. Not that I ever thought it was.

Comment: Well, you were using it as if it was, so...

Comment: I was using it to allocate memory. By the way, which part of my question was unclear or showed no research effort? I've been on this site and others searching for similar issues for the last three hours. If that was indeed you, I don't appreciate snobby downvotes, simply for being a 3-month old C programmer.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
char **colors = malloc(8);
```

you allocate only 8 *bytes* to the variable `colors`. Not enough to store six strings. If you want eight strings, why not simply create an array of eight strings?

```
char *colors[8] = { NULL };
```

The above declaration declares `colors` as an array of eight pointers to `char`, all pointers initialized to `NULL`.

If you desperately need to allocate of the heap, then you do e.g.

```
char **colors = calloc(8, sizeof(char *));
```

I use `calloc` to make sure that the allocated memory is zero-initialized (i.e. all pointers will be `NULL`).

---

Furthermore, `sscanf` does not automatically allocate space for the strings it scans, you have to do it manually. The easiest is probably to use the `'m'` modifier to the format code, like

```
sscanf(input, "%ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms",
       &color[0], &color[1], &color[2], &color[3], &color[4], &color[5]);
```

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I'm using the double pointer is so I can return it in a function. From what I understand, I can't return an array, correct? This is my dilemma. I did try allocating more memory to **colors, but still does the same thing. The reason I had allocated such a low amount was because I thought I only needed a handful of addresses, one to each element of *color[].

Comment: @mosdellg Then check out my line in the answer with the `calloc` call. And it's correct that you can't return a pointer to a local array from a function. And remember that the size provided to `malloc` is the number of *bytes*, and that a pointer is usually four (on 32-bit platforms) or eight (on 64-bit platforms) bytes.